# Having trouble using the ajax call with my giphy api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, giphy-api

I am very new to using jQuery and js. What I'm trying to do with the ajax or get method is that I want to type in any keyword(such as maine coon for example), click submit and be able to see a page of maine coon gifs. The api code I have is from giphy.

```js
function searchGif (){
        var input = Document.GetElementById("Search_Form");
        input.val();
            var input = $('#search').val();
            $.get('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q='+input+'&api_key=apikey&limit=20',function(response)
            {
                $('#img').html("<img src="+response.data[20].images.downsized_large.url+">")
            }
            )
        }
        $.get({'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q='+input+'&api_key=apikey&limit=20',function(response)
        {
            $('#img').html("<img src="+response.data[20].images.downsized_large.url+">")
        }
    })
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style1.css" />
    <script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <title>API Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <input id="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">  
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchgifs" type="submit" onclick="getData()">Search</button>
    </action>
    

   <br> 
   <br>
<script></script>
<!--<div class="inner">
    <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/hRPoV9O14t3vW/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/GBbkH7cJiVu9y/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/HXpzpXB5syQGQ/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/X9Y9qYPUp1VMQ/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/uuocoePH1mkVy/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/4ml290TZ35zOM/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/8O6EY0lahfInC/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/A7GowSMfBhq6Y/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/dQxSeXsXtf2Lu/giphy.gif" />
    <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PzrPi0UVzgYHm/giphy.gif" />
    
</div>-->
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few issues here:

- You cannot have spaces in `id` attributes, nor can you have multiple values in a single `id`. Use `class` attributes for that.
- Your `$.get()` syntax is wrong; there's extra `{}` characters which are not necessary and causing an error
- `Document.GetElementById()` needs to be `document.getElementById()` - JS is case sensitive
- Element objects do not have a `val()` method, that's only available on a jQuery object
- You're using the 'slim' branch of jQuery which does not have AJAX methods (amongst others). Use the full version of jQuery.
- The 'search' `input` is missing the `#search` id you reference in the JS to get its value
- The function you create is named `searchGif()`, not `getData()` as you use in the `onclick` attribute of the HTML.
- That said, do not use `onX` event attributes as they are outdated and no longer good practice. Attach your event handlers unobtrusively instead.
- There may not always be 21 items or more in the response, so remove `[20]` and use either `[0]` to get the first item only, or loop through them all.

With all that said, here's a working example:

```js
$('#searchgifs').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('#search').val();      
  $.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + input + '&api_key=apikey&limit=20', function(response) {
    $('#img').html("<img src=" + response.data[0].images.downsized_large.url + ">")
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="cat">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchgifs" type="submit">Search</button>

<div id="img"></div>
```